# modal input fields and button not clickable when used as view Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have created a button on my home page that opens up a modal box with input textfields and a button. I have the button with following HTML and JS

```
<div id="loginResult"></div>
<button id="login" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>


$(function(){
    $('#login').click(function(){
        $( "#loginResult" ).load( "<?php echo site_url('Main/openLogin')?>" );
    })
})
```

CSS

```
.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}


.modal-footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    bottom: 2%;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}


.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: HelveticaNeve, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;  
}


.modalDialog:target {
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fefefe;  
}



.close {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

In views I have the modal

```
 <div id="openLogin" class="modalDialog">
    <div class="model-content">
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <div class="modal-header"><h1>Login</h1></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                  if (isset($logout_message)) {
                  echo "<div class='message'>";
                  echo $logout_message;
                  echo "</div>";
                  }
                ?>

                <?php
                  if (isset($message_display)) {
                  echo "<div class='message'>";
                  echo $message_display;
                  echo "</div>";
                  }
                ?>

                <div id="main">
                    <div id="login">                        
                        <hr/>
                            <?php echo form_open('user_authentication/user_login_process'); ?>

                            <?php
                              echo "<div class='error_msg'>";
                              if (isset($error_message)) {
                              echo $error_message;
                              }
                              echo validation_errors();
                              echo "</div>";
                            ?>

                            <label>UserName :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="name" placeholder="username"/><br /><br />
                            <label>Password &nbsp;:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="**********"/><br/><br />
                            <button type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"/>Login</button><br/>
                            <br/>                            
                        <hr/>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/user_authentication/user_registration_show">To SignUp Click Here</a>

                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"><h3></h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and in the controller I have

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

    public function openLogin() {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

}
```

The problem I have is that if I just stick the modal code on the home page and get it to open with the button, all is fine. I can click on the text boxes, type text and click the login button. But when I put in views like I have above I can click the button to open the modal, which it does, but I cannot click or type in any of the textfields or click on the login button.

EDIT - added CSS if that helps

Comment: Any console errors outputted? What do you mean by it working if you stick the modal code on the homepage? Stick it where?

Comment: If I place the modal code in the body of the home page and change the button code so that when pressed it open the modal rather than a view it works correctly. The modal opens, I can enter a username and password in the input fields and click login and will be redirected to another page, same goes for the signup link. However with the code I posted above the modal will appear when the login button is clicked but the nither the inputfields, buttons or link are clickable.

Comment: See fiddle, can't click on anything - https://jsfiddle.net/r0w385cm/1/

Comment: remove "  pointer-events: none; " from " .modalDialog " class. It will prevent any pointer events.

Comment: Thanks, Can't believe I missed that.